# using google analytic with blogger dynamic views?

Tags: google-analytics, blogger

How can be possible to use Google analytic with blogger dynamic views? I cannot add the tracking code to dynamic viewed blogger blog of mine

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got to SETTINGS - OTHER and scroll to the bottom and paste your web ID from Google Analytics. It's so simple, no matter what template.

Analytics Web Property ID = ...